# Finite Group and normal Subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $d,m\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $d,m\geq 1$ and $\gcd(d,m)=1$.
Let $G$ be a group of order $dm$ and define the set $X:= \{g\in G | g^d=1\}$.

> Show: if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with order d then $H=X$.

My idea was to use the theorem : if $|H|$ and $(G:H)$ are coprime, then $H$ is the only subgroup of $G$ of order $d$.
Therefore I need to show that $|X|=d$.
I tried this:
For $g\in X$, $g\not= e$, $o(g)/d$ and $o(g) /|X|$ and $o(g)/|G| = dm$.
Since $(d,m)=1$ we have $o(g)\not| m$ and so $|X|/d$.
But now I don't know how to show that $d/|X|$ as well.

Am I right?Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You are missing something - you have not used $a$ in the statement of the question. Are you also assuming that the index $|G:H|=a$? (You seem to use this in your proof...)

Comment: Sorry! I changed a and b to d and m while writing! Thank you

Comment: I am confused by " Show: if $|H|=d$ a normal subgroup in $G$"

Comment: I shell show the implication: $|H|=d$, and $H$ normal in G $\Rightarrow$ $H=X$. Sorry for being unclear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to prove:

1. $H\subseteq X$, by Lagrange.
2. $X\subseteq H$. To see this, consider the quotient group $G/H$. Suppose $x\in X$. Then $(xH)^d=x^dH=H$. This means that $xH$ has order dividing $d$. Apply Lagrange, we have that $xH=H$, so $x\in H$ as required.

These combine to prove the result.

---

Finally - a quick note on your attempt. You said that you want to show that $|X|=d$, and your logic was that you knew that $H$ was the only subgroup of order $d$. *However*, $X$ is not necessarily a subgroup! For example, the permutations $(123)$ and $(345)$ both have order $3$, but they multiply to give $(1 2 3 4 5)$, a permutation of order $5$.

Comment: (Exercise: Spot where I used the normality of $H$.)

Comment: I just read your comment more carefully. I thought I had $x,y\in X$ $\Rightarrow x^d=y^d=1$ $\Rightarrow$ $x*y\in X$ since $(x*y)^d=x^d*y^d$ (I guess this step not valid as for your example?)
To your answer, I am still working on it :) I don't see yet why $(xH)^d=x^d H$ and how you applied Lagrange. But I'll try a bit more. Thanks for your hints!

Comment: @Luca $(x\ast y)^d\neq x^d\ast y^d$ in general. You need commutativity to make it work.

Comment: Too see that $(xH)^d=x^dH$, notice that $xHxH=x(xHx^{-1})xH=x^2H$, by normality of $H$ (in general, $gHhH=ghH$).

Comment: My application of Lagrange is because $G/H$ is a group with elements of the form $gH$, and multiplication $gHhH=ghH$, and it has order $m$.

Comment: OK thanks! Another question. Isn't xH and H always of the same order since $\psi: H \rightarrow xH$ is a bijection? So $\# xH=\# H$ automatically no?

Comment: And another question.. I still don't see how you got the result $xH=H$ from the Lagrange theorem. I see that $(G:H)=m$ but not the other result.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Luca They are both sets with the same number of elements, we are considering these cosets as elements of the group $G/H$. So when I said "order" I meant "order of the element $xH$ in the group $G/H$".

Comment: @Luca $xH$ has order dividing $d$, but by Lagrange the only element in $G/H$ which has order dividing $d$ is the trivial element, $H$.

Comment: Ok I think I understood.
Can I explain it like that: $H\in G/H$ is the neutral element. So from $(xH)^d=H$ we know $ord(xH)|d$ but $ord(xH)|\# G/H = m$ (since every element divides the order of its group) and since $m$ and $d$ are coprime we get that $ord(xH)=1=ord(H)$ and so $xH=H$. Is that OK? (and, don't we know from $xH=H$ already that $X\subseteq H$ since $x$ was arbitrary no?)

Comment: @Luca You explanation is correct. And yes, you are right that if $xH=H$ then $x\in H$. I'll edit this into my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!